# fetching android app's information in PHP

Tags: php, json, cakephp, app-store, google-play

I've been looking for some mechanism through which I can fetch android app's information such as app's ID in market, it's category, pricing, its icon and likewise from Google Play. I know there's a facility for App store for iOS, in which we can fetch app's information through URL below, which returns us back JSON of it:

http://itunes.apple.com/search?media=software&term=[query_word]

I need same for Android Market. Is there any URL for doing the same?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is Android Market API ported to PHP:
https://github.com/splitfeed/android-market-api-php

Comment: I know this API but I can't integrate it with cakephp. there's something wrong.

Comment: there are some functions that are conflicting with each other in cakephp and this API.

Comment: It should not be so, because that API is based on classes, do you mean classes have same names? How do you include it into your project?

Comment: yeah, classes have same names. I've put it in Vendor folder and called in file where I want this functionality.

Comment: Easy way - just rename API's conflicting classes to unique ones